# semop( ) failed with errno 4. Dose semop() support threads' race inside a process?

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

I have two threads in a process. These two threads have a race to a share memory which is attempting to be synchronized by semaphore. But I randomly got a failure with errno 4 when one threads is next to the other to call semop function. I did a little digging and found it looks to seem that calling was interrupted by system call.

EINTR  While blocked in this system call, the process caught a signal; see              signal(7). errno 4 is this one?

Please note lines 583 and 601.

which system call interrupted it? the function semop() itself? Any way to ignore this system call interrupting or recover/restart this function?

semop can be used in a multi-thread environment?

```
[Switching to Thread -1208269120 (LWP 4501)]
GetMyQue2Wait (MyModule=RM, wait_shm_ptr=0xbf8a5cf4) at tdm_ipc.c:247
247                                             TDM_SEM_P( MyModule );
(gdb) s
tdm_sem_p (mid=RM) at tdm_ipc.c:579
579             sem_b.sem_num = 0;
(gdb) s
580             sem_b.sem_op = -1;
(gdb) s
581             sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
(gdb) s
583             if (semop(TDM_M[mid].semid, &sem_b, 1) == -1)
(gdb) s
[Switching to Thread -1208480880 (LWP 4506)]

GetMyQue2Send (MyModule=RM, send_shm_ptr=0xb7f7ff54) at tdm_ipc.c:180
180             DMINT           TryTimes = SEND_TIMES;
(gdb) s
353             TDM_SEM_V( DstModule );
(gdb) s
tdm_sem_v (mid=RM) at tdm_ipc.c:597
597             sem_b.sem_num = 0;
(gdb) s
598             sem_b.sem_op = 1;
(gdb) s
599             sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
(gdb) s
601             if (semop(TDM_M[mid].semid, &sem_b, 1) == -1)
(gdb) s
606             return SUCC;
(gdb) s
607     }


(gdb) s
RM:4501: V operation on Semaphore .
SEND_MSG (SrcModule=51, DstModule=RM, msg_ptr=0xb7f7ff94, MsgLength=28) at tdm_ipc.c:368
368             printf("%s:%d: SEND_MSG: succeeded.\n",
(gdb) s
RM:4501: SEND_MSG: succeeded.
[Switching to Thread -1208269120 (LWP 4501)]
tdm_sem_p (mid=RM) at tdm_ipc.c:585
585                     printf("thread %u: errno = %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),errno);
(gdb) s
thread 3086698176: errno = 4
[Switching to Thread -1208480880 (LWP 4506)]



 main thread:

        ...
         while(1)
           {
                 if ((RetVal = WAIT_MSG( p1, &Msg )) !=SUCC)
                 {
                     switch ( RetVal )
                     {
                     ...
                      }
                  }
            }
     ------------------------------------  
        thread1:
        ...
        send(src, dst, &msg, lenght);

        /* both SEND_MSG() and WAIT_MSG() have an operation P and V on semid by calling the following */

        DMINT tdm_sem_p( key_t semid )
        {
           struct sembuf sem_b;

           sem_b.sem_num = 0;
           sem_b.sem_op = -1;
           sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

           if (semop(semid, &sem_b, 1) == -1)
           {
              printf("thread %u: errno = %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(),errno);

              return S_PFAIL;
           }

           return SUCC;
        }

        DMINT tdm_sem_v( key_t semid )
        {
           struct sembuf sem_b;

           sem_b.sem_num = 0;
           sem_b.sem_op = 1;
           sem_b.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

           if (semop(semid, &sem_b, 1) == -1)
           {
              return S_VFAIL;
           }

           return SUCC;
        }

        /* semid is init by the following */
        DMINT tdm_set_sem(key_t semid)
        {
           union semun sem_union;
           sem_union.val = 1;

           if (semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, sem_union) == -1)
           {
              return FAILURE;
           }
           return SUCC;
        }
```

this problem have a another link which may have a bad problem description.
[P semaphore failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577631/p-semaphore-failed)

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your code snippet too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Errno 4 is indeed `EINTR`. When you get that error, it means the system call you were running (`semop` in this case) was interrupted by a signal.

You're responsible for restarting the system call in that case. Only a limited set of system calls restart automatically, and then only if the signal handler was set up using the `SA_RESTART` flag. See [`signal(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) for the details on that, "Interruption of System Calls and Library Functions by Signal Handlers" section. You'll notice `semop` is in the list of system calls that is *never* restarted, regardless of the disposition of the signal handler.

How you restart the call is up to you. One of the ways is to do something like:

```
int rc;

while ((rc = semop(...)) == -1) {
  if (errno != EINTR) {
    break;
  } else {
    // decide whether to restart the call after interruption
    // or not
  }
}
// here, if rc == 0, semop worked, otherwise an error different from
// EINTR happened (or you decided not to restart)
```

You don't know what signal interrupted a given system call unless you have a handler for that signal. `gdb` does have [options for signal handling](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_39.html) though, so you could try and find out with that. Try `handle all print` to start with maybe.

Answer (score 0):

strace the process in question...when the semop fails, you should see the signal being emitted that interrupts it.